# add child to xmlNode in R

Tags: r

I am trying to add a child to a child using XML package in R.
the following fails:

```
library(XML)
node1 <- c("val1","val2","val3")
names(node1) <- c("att1","att2","att3")
root <- xmlNode("root", attrs=node1)

node2 <- LETTERS[1:3]
names(node2) <- paste("name",1:3,sep="")

root <- addChildren(root,xmlNode("child1",attrs=node2))

node3 <- letters[1:3]
names(node3) <- paste("name",4:6,sep="")

root <- addChildren(root$child1,xmlNode("child2",attrs=node3))
```

Error in UseMethod("addChildren") : 
  no applicable method for 'addChildren' applied to an object of class "NULL"

Answer (score 1):

To call a childnode of a parentnode, you need to use `[[]]`. You can call the childnodes by either index or by name. So changing the last line to either

```
root[["child1"]] <- addChildren(root[["child1"]],xmlNode("child2",attrs=node3))
```

or

```
root[[1]] <- addChildren(root[[1]],xmlNode("child2",attrs=node3))
```

results in

```
<root att1="val1" att2="val2" att3="val3">
 <child1 name1="A" name2="B" name3="C">
  <child2 name4="a" name5="b" name6="c"/>
 </child1>
</root>
```